# Why do I need to reboot after updating Airport Utility to version 6.3.1?

Tags: macos, airport, reboot

Why do I need to reboot after updating Airport Utility to version 6.3.1?  Is there some kind of serious kernel tweaks involved in Apple's new router tool?  Since when does a robust UNIX operating system need to REBOOT after an update to a basic router utility.  A device which has no bearing whatsoever on the core functions OS X.  I'm dumbfounded by this.  Not only that but it took a whopping 3 minutes to apply the patch.

Somebody please break this down for me.

Comment: Without more information from you it is not possible to answer. On my MBA 10.8.4 the update 6.3.1 did not require reboot!

Comment: I also didn't have to reboot. Likely Airport Utility wasn't the only update as I installed it on 3 of my Macs and none required a reboot.

Comment: thanks. i had previously installed some other updates and already rebooted once.  software update showed only the Airport Utility 6.3.1 update and nothing else.  perhaps the second reboot was somehow related to my previous updates.  pretty strange nonetheless, but at least it's reassuring to know that this isn't standard policy on this update.

Comment: I've installed the AirPort utility on several Macs and there was no reboot required. Perhaps by editing in a link to the package you installed (or looking in /var/log/install.log you might see another package caused the reboot instead of product 091-7170 / Airport Utility)

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."  Please Clarify what's unclear here @bmike.  (1) Software update told me Airport update 6.3.1 was available, with no mention of any other updates.  (2) After applying said update I was told that I now needed to reboot. (3) I asked the question "Why do I need to reboot after updating Airport Utility to version 6.3.1?".  Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: ON your suggestion I did check the install log and have found that software update did indeed install "Security Update 2013-003".  I am long time OS X user and please trust me when I say that I WAS NOT informed of this when I ok'd the update to airport utility.  At least this explains what happened and why it happened, but leaves me with another question.  Why didn't software update tell me it was applying a security patch or ask my permission?

Comment: Both the GUI and the terminal version of software update clearly mention the reboot for the security update and not for the airport update. Either you didn't read carefully enough or your software is broken in that respect. I don't see how anyone could tell which is the case given the lack of detail in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known reason why upgrading an Airport Basestation or Airport Utility should lead to a reboot (and I've never run into this situation either). The best guess (as already stated in the comments above) is that another upgrade was applied at the same time which required a reboot afterwards. Whether you just didn't realize the additional upgrade or it somehow "sneaked" into the upgrade process due to a bug/race condition in the Software Updater is something which is probably impossible to analyze post-factum.